# Pandas - Convert String type to Float

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in a DF. How could I convert this column into a float(13,5) with 5 decimals.String length is always 18 characters. As a workaround , I have used string split function and joined return values.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['+00000030454360000','-00000030734250000','-00000004643685000'],columns=['qty'])
print df.qty.str[:13]+'.'+df.qty.str[13:]
```

Expected Output

```
                    0
0  +304543.6
1  -307342.5
2  -46436.85
```

Comment: in the question you stated that you need `float(13,5)`, but in the desired data set you have strings. So do you need modified strings  or floats?

Comment: @ MaxU Just realized the mistake:)  I need float value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [23]: pd.to_numeric(df.qty, errors='coerce') / 10**5
Out[23]:
0    304543.60
1   -307342.50
2    -46436.85
Name: qty, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU.. I was expecting an answer from you

Comment: @Shijo, glad i could help :-)